# Lock iPhone App Orientation throughout

Tags: ios, iphone, orientation

I gather the orientation approach changed in the recent version of iOS and I'm not using UIWebView...

Is there a way of locking an entire App to Portrait Mode or do I have to force each View Controller?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I disable landscape orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785565/how-can-i-disable-landscape-orientation)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In iOS 7 you can check only portrait in project-> general -> Deployment info.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks - I'd conditioned myself into thinking it would be a programming solution. EH

Answer (score 8):

Go to Xcode > "General" and edit:[image]

Answer (score 6):

Following is the way to lock the orientation of your app to portrait only.

[image: How to lock orientation of your app to portrait only]