# How to block landscape position from code, separetly for each view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, landscape-portrait

I know that I can select available orientation of my app in targets menu, but I would like to block landscape orientation for each screen EXCEPT the one with youtube player.

I suppose this couldn't be done via app delegate since it does not distinct controllers and apply the rule for the whole app.

I suspect maybe there is a way to do that via sharedApplication(), but have no clue how to.

Do you have any idea how such thing could be done?

Comment: possibly duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785565/how-can-i-disable-landscape-orientation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the UIViewController class you wish to set to Portrait only.

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
  return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
}
```

Provided you haven't changed any settings in your target the other screens without this should be able to rotate correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `override func` in each VC you want to block `.LandscapeLeft` and `.LandscapeRight`

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue) | Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.PortraitUpsideDown.rawValue)
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work with a UINavigationController. The portrait-only screen ends up in landscape.